# How can I increase and decrease the quantity in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I have a button and an input form. When clicking the button, my product quantity decreases by 1 and increases quantity when submitting the form. Quantity increases with the form value. How can I complete this problem in Reactjs?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const InventoryDetails = () => {
  const [inventory, setInventory] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = `inventory.json`;

    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setInventory(data));
  }, []);

  const handleDelivered = () => {
    // can't understand what can I do here.
  };
  const restockItem = () => {};

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h6> Quantity: {inventory.quantity} </h6>

        <button onClick={handleDelivered}>Delivered</button>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h3>Restock the items</h3>
        <form onSubmit={restockItem}>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="number"
            id=""
            placeholder="Enter quantity"
            required
          />

          <input className="" type="submit" value="Restock" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you please add the code you're having trouble with?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I put my code here. check again, please.

Answer (score 0):

Here I wrote two functions `handleDelivered` and `restockItem`. Put `restockItem` function to your button and try them:

```
handleDelivered = () => {
    setInventory({
        ...inventory,
        quantity: inventory.quantity - 1,
    });
};

restockItem = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    setInventory({
        ...inventory,
        quantity: inventory.quantity + parseInt(event.target[0].value),
    });
};
```

You have to set the state of the inventory when you're going to make changes, `...inventory` is destructing the `inventory` object to get all the fields inside and change only `quantity` field, `preventDefault` is just my habit to prevent submitting, don't forget to type check the quantity field.

Answer (score -2):

You can use these tricks to solve this problem -

1. When you add or remove quantity from your stocks you can also update the database also using a 'PUT' method and set a dependency on your use effect over product. So when the product data updated in the database its also updated in the UI because of the dependency.